# Is there a Python equivalent of Ruby's officer gem?

Tags: python, ruby, locking, distributed-computing

Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's [officer](https://github.com/chadrem/officer) gem? It is a distributed locking server, basically allows you to have locks across a network rather than just between threads.

I've been looking at [elock](http://dustin.github.com/elock/) which has a Python library for it, however elock is unlicensed so we can't really use it for commercial software (also it has more or less been abandoned).

Ideally the equivalent will fit into twisted, but that's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using [memcached](http://memcached.org/) since it has atomic updates.

The solution is fairly simple:

```
import memcache

mc = memcache.Client(hosts, debug=1)

# to lock:
def request_lock(key, timeout=300):
    if mc == None:
        raise Exception("Memcache is not connected!")

    # just store a "1" in that location - this is an atomic operation so if two
    # nodes request a lock at the same time, only one of them will get a True
    return mc.add(key, "1", timeout)

# to unlock:
def request_unlock(key):
    if mc == None:
        raise Exception("Memcache is not connected!")

    return mc.delete(key) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are doing is for an asymmetric project, look at the list [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing).  It has a section on cluster computing using python, the two most promising looking are [celery](https://github.com/celery/celery) and [pp](http://www.parallelpython.com/).  The page also has resources for splitting tasks up between processes on one computer.  It may also work with symmetric projects, but I think the locks pretty much have to be owned by the 'server'.

Comment: Thanks for the resources! However it doesn't really answer the question - I'm looking for a way to lock resources over a network, not just for general resources for parallel computing with Python.